# Should I put a disclaimer while answering with low confidence?

Tags: discussion, answers

I got a doubt while reading a textbook yesterday and I [asked a question](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/28166/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-distributional-semantics-and-distributed-se) on the same day.

Today I got some insights regarding it after reading whole unit. But, I am not fully confident whether I am correct.

Anyway, i tried to provide [an answer](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/28196/18758) according to my own insights. And kept on the top of the answer: *I am writing the answer according to my current understanding*

Should I keep that as banner or is it okay to provide my own interpretation as an answer and then react accordingly based on comments, down-votes to the answer?

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if there are any... "official" rules for something like this on the site. Probably not. Personally, I think it's always useful to explicitly mention when you're not sure or confident about something though. The more specific you can make this, the better. If I'm sure about a large part of my answer, but not about a small detail somewhere, I'd explicitly mention it there. If you can also concretely describe **why** you're not sure about something, or which assumptions you make (that may be wrong) that lead you to whatever conclusion you're not 100% sure about, even better!

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what was written in the other answer, which I agree with (so, generally, if you think you're unsure about something you should inform the reader, as misinformation can hurt the readers), I think it's important to note that, ideally, people that are also familiar with the topic or know whether your answer is correct or not are expected to upvote or downvote your answer (depending on whether it's correct or incorrect) or leave a comment.

So, even if you didn't leave that disclaimer, in my view, incorrect answers should be downvoted, independently of whether the OP will fix the mistakes later or not (note that I didn't even read your answer and I don't really know if it's correct or not, but this is a general suggestion). Downvoting should not be used to personally attack someone, but it's our tool to determine what is good/correct/useless or bad/incorrect/useful content, but, unfortunately, not all people understand this.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends also partly on the question.  If it's a formal question, or a hard science question, with a precise, provable answer, disclaimer would be good, and acceptance of downvotes if other's deem it incorrect.  (OK to remove also.)

For fuzzy questions, which I often answer a lot of on other stacks, I'll directly say "this is my guess" before I make a supportable, well reasoned argument, because there is no source that has answered it, or there may even be differences of opinion.

("What is the difference between a sword and a knife" on martial arts, as an example. I've never been able to find an answer, but now that I've studied them sufficiently, significantly more than most people, I'm confident I can answer it, and the correctness of that answer will be validated by the argument.)

The humanities stacks, such as Literature, don't often have objective answers, and are more about providing analysis which may benefit students and scholars.  Sometimes an OP will accept the one they most agree with, but, in those cases, all well reasoned answers are valuable.

We have some fuzziness in the case of philosophy and social aspects, but those questions are more rare here.